# Chart is not rendered and throws script error, if yaxis contains null dateTime data and useUTC is false

Tags: datetime, highcharts, yaxis

I am trying to plot date on yaxis on column chart with all null values so empty chart is expected as output with useUTC set to false.
But it gives script errors on console.
When I set useUTC to true then it will plot empty chart.
Thanks in advance.
Expected: empty chart to be plotted.
Check below fiddle for reference.
https://jsfiddle.net/2ekch139/1/

```
     Highcharts.setOptions({
   global: {
     useUTC: false
   }
 });
 Highcharts.chart('container', {

   "chart": {
     "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
     "plotBackgroundColor": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
     "zoomType": "xy",
     "resetZoomButton": {
       "theme": {
         "visibility": "hidden"
       }
     },
     "alignTicks": true,
     "options3d": {
       "enabled": false
     },
     "renderTo": {},
     "events": {}
   },
   "title": {
     "text": ".",
     "style": {
       "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)",
       "fontSize": "1px"
     }
   },
   "tooltip": {
     "enabled": true,
     "borderWidth": 1,
     "borderRadius": 1,
     "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
     "style": {
       "color": "#000000",
       "fontSize": "1rem",
       "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
       "fontWeight": "normal",
       "fontStyle": "normal",
       "textDecoration": "none"
     },
     "useHTML": true,
     "shared": false,
     "crosshairs": [false, false],
     "followPointer": true
   },
   "plotOptions": {
     "series": {
       "animation": {
         "duration": 700
       },
       "cursor": "pointer",
       "allowPointSelect": true,
       "showInLegend": true,
       "turboThreshold": 0,
       "stickyTracking": false,
       "events": {},
       "point": {
         "events": {}
       },
       "pointPadding": 0.1,
       "getExtremesFromAll": true
     }
   },
   "legend": {
     "enabled": true,
     "item": {},
     "borderWidth": 0,
     "layout": "horizontal",

     "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
     "itemStyle": {
       "color": "#000000",
       "fontSize": "1rem",
       "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
       "fontWeight": "normal",
       "fontStyle": "normal",
       "textDecoration": "none"
     },
     "align": "center",
     "verticalAlign": "bottom",
     "margin": 0,
     "padding": 5,
     "symbolRadius": 0
   },
   "credits": {
     "enabled": false
   },
   "exporting": {
     "enabled": false
   },
   "lang": {
     "noData": ""
   },
   "xAxis": {
     "title": {
       "text": "xaxis",
       "style": {
         "color": "#000000",
         "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
         "fontSize": "1rem",
         "fontStyle": "normal",
         "fontWeight": "normal",
         "textDecoration": "none",
         "opacity": "1"
       },
       "align": "middle",
       "margin": 5
     },
     "opposite": false,
     "axisInternalName": "0",
     "labels": {
       "enabled": true,
       "style": {
         "color": "#000000",
         "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
         "fontSize": "1rem",
         "fontStyle": "normal",
         "fontWeight": "normal",
         "textDecoration": "none"
       },
       "rotation": 330
     },
     "lineWidth": 1,
     "lineColor": "rgba(174,174,174,1)",
     "id": "xAxis0",
     "tickWidth": 1,
     "categories": ["01/10/2001 00:00:00", "01/12/2001 00:00:00", "01/09/2006 00:00:00", "01/12/2012 00:00:00"],
     "tickmarkPlacement": "on",
     "gridLineWidth": 0,
     "gridLineColor": "#C0C0C0",
     "plotLines": [],
     "plotBands": [],
     "max": null,
     "scrollbar": {
       "enabled": false

     }
   },
   "yAxis": [{
     "title": {
       "text": "yaxis",
       "style": {
         "color": "#000000",
         "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
         "fontSize": "1rem",
         "fontStyle": "normal",
         "fontWeight": "normal",
         "textDecoration": "none",
         "opacity": "1"
       },
       "align": "middle",
       "margin": 5
     },
     "opposite": false,
     "axisInternalName": "0",
     "labels": {
       "enabled": true,
       "style": {
         "color": "#000000",
         "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
         "fontSize": "1rem",
         "fontStyle": "normal",
         "fontWeight": "normal",
         "textDecoration": "none"
       },
       "rotation": 0,
       "align": "center"
     },
     "lineWidth": 0,
     "lineColor": "rgba(174,174,174,1)",
     "tickWidth": 0,
     "allowDecimals": false,
     "reversed": false,
     "id": "yAxis0",
     "gridLineWidth": 0,
     "gridLineColor": "#C0C0C0",
     "maxPadding": 0.05,
     "minPadding": 0,
     "plotLines": [],
     "plotBands": [],
     "type": "datetime",
     "startOnTick": false
   }],
   "boost": {
     "enabled": false,
     "seriesThreshold": 2
   },
   "series": [{
     "zIndex": 1,
     "internalName": "CustomerSale__Custom_Product__Msr_ORDER_DATE",

     "softThreshold": true,
     "type": "column",
     "yAxis": 0,

     "data": [null, null, null, null],
     "name": "series name",
     "showInLegend": true,
     "dataLabels": {
       "enabled": false
     },
     "tooltipBackgroundColor": "#ffffff",
     "point": {
       "events": {}
     },
     "boostThreshold": 5001,
     "color": "rgba(0,41,170,1)",
     "borderColor": "rgba(0,41,170,1)",
     "fillColor": "rgba(0,41,170,1)",
     "depth": 40,
     "states": {
       "select": {
         "color": null
       }
     },
     "borderWidth": 0,
     "maxPointWidth": "70",
     "id": "series0"
   }]

 });
```

It throws script errors on console as -

```
highcharts.src.js:10151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Time.getTimezoneOffset (highcharts.src.js:10151)
    at Time.getTimeTicks (highcharts.src.js:10411)
    at Axis.q.getTimeTicks (stock.src.js:3771)
    at Axis.setTickPositions (highcharts.src.js:15873)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a regression. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where this thread will be continued.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14746

Comment: Thanks @sebastian Wedzel for replying. Can please tell me the version where this fix will be available? currently, I have version 8.2.2

Comment: @PurvaKshatriya it's already fixed, so it is available on the master branch and will be available in the npm after the next release.

Comment: Okay. By any chance, it their any patch fix or customization which I can add to patch fix this issue till next release. And what is probable date of next release?

Comment: You can use the master branch in your app: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1wg63hso/

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much @Sebastian Wedzel.